# How to set Tap target for Bottom navigation

Tags: android, android-studio, taptargetview

I use keepsafe tap target for creating tap targets. For every view, it works fine but when I use it for bottom navigation it gives me null pointer exception error.
I have read its document. In that document has been written that I should use TapTarget.forBounds but it has Null pointer exception error.
How should I use it?
This is my code:

```
TapTarget t = TapTarget.forBounds(bottomNavigationViewEx.getBottomNavigationItemView(R.id.ic_shoppingCenter).getClipBounds(),"Title","Description")
                    .cancelable(false)
                    .drawShadow(true)
                    .dimColor(android.R.color.tab_indicator_text)
                    .outerCircleColor(android.R.color.holo_blue_dark)
                    .targetCircleColor(android.R.color.holo_green_dark)
                    .transparentTarget(true)
                    .targetRadius(32)
                    .outerCircleAlpha(0.96f)
                    .titleTextSize(15)
                    .descriptionTextSize(12)
                    .descriptionTextColor(android.R.color.white)
                    .textColor(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright)
                    .titleTextColor(android.R.color.white)
                    .tintTarget(false);
```

Comment: on which line .whats in the logs?

Comment: @kelvin in first line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
TapTarget.forView(navView.findViewById(R.id.ic_shoppingCenter),
```

I am using it like this and it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm gonna check that

Comment: I think for you that's bottomNavigationViewEx

Comment: could you please check that my problem? no one answers me! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67659325/why-poster-library-crashes-when-i-add-video . Thank you in advance