# Why Poster library crashes when I add video

Tags: android, android-viewpager, slider

I use this library "com.github.mohan-dev1248:PosterSlider:1.0.2" for image and video slider in recyclerview adapter(I want to create something like instagram).
But when I add a video into my list for the slider, the application crashes with this log:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The application's PagerAdapter changed the adapter's contents without calling PagerAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged! Expected adapter item count: 1, found: 2 Pager id: com.example.koohestantest1.tak:id/ps_newsItem Pager class: class androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager Problematic adapter: class com.example.koohestantest1.classDirectory.NewsLetterViewPagerAdapter
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1143)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1092)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1622)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19858)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19858)
        at androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(NestedScrollView.java:1599)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView.onMeasure(NestedScrollView.java:585)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19858)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.measureChildWithMargins(RecyclerView.java:9678)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1657)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1591)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:668)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4309)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:4012)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4578)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17638)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1855)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17638)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17638)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1855)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17638)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17638)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17638)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17638)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17638)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:727)
2021-05-23 15:58:07.060 7749-7749/com.example.koohestantest1.tak E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17638)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2346)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2068)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1254)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6338)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:874)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:621)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:860)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6198)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:891)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:781)
2021-05-23 15:58:07.576 1880-1880/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 1880: eglCreateSyncKHR(1584): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
2021-05-23 15:58:12.677 2178-4083/? E/ActivityManager: Found activity ActivityRecord{e6de0ad u0 com.example.koohestantest1.tak/com.example.koohestantest1.activity.Main2Activity t43 f} in proc activity list using null instead of expected ProcessRecord{304539e 7749:com.example.koohestantest1.tak/u0a74}
2021-05-23 15:58:12.793 1892-7874/? E/IMediaHTTPConnection: remote readAt failed
2021-05-23 15:58:12.793 1892-7874/? E/NuCachedSource2: source returned error -2147483648, 10 retries left
2021-05-23 15:58:12.965 1880-1880/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 1880: eglCreateSyncKHR(1584): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
2021-05-23 15:58:17.715 2553-6664/? E/WakeLock: GCM_HB_ALARM release without a matched acquire!
2021-05-23 16:03:07.928 2553-6664/? E/WakeLock: GCM_HB_ALARM release without a matched acquire!
2021-05-23 16:04:10.165 2178-2194/? E/BatteryStatsService: no controller energy info supplied
2021-05-23 16:04:10.165 2178-2194/? E/BatteryStatsService: no controller energy info supplied
2021-05-23 16:04:10.167 2178-2194/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state (No such file or directory)
2021-05-23 16:04:10.167 2178-2194/? E/KernelUidCpuTimeReader: Failed to read uid_cputime: /proc/uid_cputime/show_uid_stat (No such file or directory)
2021-05-23 16:04:10.168 2178-2194/? E/BatteryStatsService: modem info is invalid: ModemActivityInfo{ mTimestamp=0 mSleepTimeMs=0 mIdleTimeMs=0 mTxTimeMs[]=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] mRxTimeMs=0 mEnergyUsed=0}
```

I try a lot of things but I did not understand where should I use notifyDataSetChange.
This is how I use the slider in onBindViewHolder of recyclerView:

```
        RemoteImage remoteImage;
        RemoteVideo remoteVideo;


        newsId = newsLetterList.get(position).NewsID;
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(newsLetterList.get(position).Jsonsrc);
            posterList.clear();
            for(int i = 0;i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                if(jsonArray.getString(i).contains(".jpg") || jsonArray.getString(i).contains(".jpeg") || jsonArray.getString(i).contains(".png")) {
                    remoteImage = new RemoteImage(jsonArray.getString(i));
                    remoteImage.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
                    posterList.add(remoteImage);
                }
                else {
                    remoteVideo = new RemoteVideo(Uri.parse(jsonArray.getString(i)));
                    posterList.add(remoteVideo);
                }
                

            }

            holder.slider.setPosters(posterList);
            NewsLetterViewPagerAdapter adapter = new NewsLetterViewPagerAdapter(context,posterList);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            holder.slider.setAdapter(adapter);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

So what should I do?

Comment: comment  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); and try running your application

Comment: @kelvin It does not work, I tried that

Comment: can you add a sample json to reproduce your error?

Comment: @kelvin Yes, I'm gonna do that and then tell you what happened. Thank you

Comment: @kelvin When I use static values like this: List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
            items.add("https://serverv2.nokhbgan.ir/api/Products/DownloadFileV1?src=NxhGUonzxnC_1.png");
            items.add("https://serverv2.nokhbgan.ir/api/Products/DownloadFileV1?src=NxhGUonzxnC_2.mp4");
            NewsLetterViewPagerAdapter adapter = new NewsLetterViewPagerAdapter(context, items);
            holder.slider.setAdapter(adapter); . Eveything works fine and the application does not crash. So what do you think?

Comment: add LOG for (jsonArray.getString(i)) before  _remoteVideo = new RemoteVideo(Uri.parse(jsonArray.getString(i)));_ line .see what you are getting just before your app crashes

Comment: @kelvin I added LOG and this is its result: 2021-05-25 10:22:52.953 10183-10183/com.example.koohestantest1.tak D/Video: https://serverv2.nokhbgan.ir/api/Products/DownloadFileV1?src=NiytCeYKJkn_1.mp4
2021-05-25 10:23:40.875 10183-10183/com.example.koohestantest1.tak D/Video: https://serverv2.nokhbgan.ir/api/Products/DownloadFileV1?src=NxhGUonzxnC_2.mp4 . it returns url correctly